# Differences between translations of ‘divorce’

Tags: difference, noun, vocabulary

I have translated divorce into German. There are three translations there:
*Scheidung f, Ehescheidung f, Trennung f*

I am studying the difference between them.

> Scheidung = gesetzliche, gerichtliche Auflösung der Ehe — DWDS
>
> Ehescheidung = gerichtliche Auflösung der Ehe — DWDS
>
> Trennung = (no entry) — DWDS

What is the difference? Which one is a law term? Which one is informal?

Comment: If you are not sure about the nuances of the translations, it might be helpful to translate the German words back to English, e.g., http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/Trennung.html

Answer (score 4):

Obviously we are dealing with two different roots here: *Scheidung* (from *scheiden)* and *Trennung* (from *trennen).* The additional modifier *Ehe-* is simply a compound component and clarifies that it is the divorce of a marriage you are talking about, which also makes *Ehescheidung* much more of a technical and law term.

According to the [etymological dictionary entry shown on DWDS.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/trennen#et-1), *trennen* — while nowadays simply meaning *to part* — originated from a root closer to *to flee.* In modern usage, it has taken over most of the meaning of the other verb *[scheiden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/scheiden#et-1),* which originally meant *to separate.*

The old meaning of *to separate* is still very present in the word *Scheidung* which is nothing short of *separating* the former maritial bond between to people. *Scheidung* is recognised as exactly the nullification of a marriage, so it implies having been legally married and legally no longer being married.

On the other hand, *Trennung* is a much broader term. As mentioned, it has taken over the general meaning of *separation* from the original word *Scheidung* — and that is exactly what it describes, the *physical* separation of what was once close or together. There is no necessary implication of marriage; instead ending *any* relationship is termed *Trennung* and some even introduce weird (to me) concepts like *Trennung auf Zeit* — separation only for a limited time.

In Germany, a *Scheidung* always has an implied previous *Trennung.* For a marriage to be declared divorced, the parties have to ‘separate bed and table for a year’ — commonly interpreted as having lived apart for at least a year.

While I have used the term *marriage* consistently and I believe German law would do so, too, I would also use *Scheidung* if I wanted to imply a registered homosexual partnership officially nullified. Note that these are not officially called *Ehe* (in spite of the colloquial *Homo-Ehe)* and thus this divorce cannot be termed *Ehescheidung* in legal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

They are synonyms, by and large, (Ehe-)Scheidung being both the common and legal term. *Trennung* simply means separation, and either dissolves some other form of relationship or possibly precedes a full-fledged divorce (such a separation, where cohabitation, as it were, is ended is in fact a requirement for a divorce in many cases.)